# Can I use these two series in a direct comparison test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can the infinite series:

$$a = \dfrac{1}{e^n}$$

Be compared to the series

$$b = \dfrac{n}{e^{n^2}}$$

such that  $a \ge b$

Can the direct comparison test be used here to prove that series set equal to
(b) converges because the series (a) is a convergent geometric series?

Comment: Actually $b <a$ for $n$ large.

Comment: yeah I just caught that too lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^n}, ~b_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^{n^2}}$$

To apply the direct comparison test, we need to show that $0\le b_n \le a_n$ for sufficiently large $n$. We have that as $n\to\infty$

$$ne^n\le e^{n^2} \implies \frac{n}{e^{n^2}} \le \frac{1}{e^n}$$

because 
$$\frac{ne^n}{e^{n^2}}\le \dfrac{n}{e^n}\to 0$$

Now, since

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^n}=\frac{1}{e-1}<\infty$$

we may conclude that $b_n$ must converge by the direct comparison test.